# Update without selecting Image get an Error (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, crud

First of all I wanted to do an update for a form, and it works fine if I select another image.

but if I'm not selecting an image, it gives a $imageName Error

```
     $request->validate([
            'type'      => 'required',
            'title'     => 'required',
            'body'      => 'required',
            'excerpt'   => 'required',
            'tag'       => 'required',
            'metas'     => 'required',
            'ispublished'     => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
        {
                request()->validate(['image' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048']);
                $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        }
        $post             =  post::find($id);
        $post->type       = $request->get('type');
        $post->slug       = str_slug($request->get('title'));
        $post->title      = $request->get('title');
        $post->body       = $request->get('body');
        $post->excerpt    = $request->get('excerpt');
        $post->tag        = $request->get('tag');
        $post->image      = $imageName;
        $post->metas       = $request->get('metas');
        $post->ispublished = $request->get('ispublished');
        $post->published_at = $request->get('published_at');
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('post.index')->with('success','Post updated successfully');
```

this is the error if i'm not selecting the image
[image]

how can i do updates, without selecting an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be better idea to update the Image column, after the updates has been done, also would work for creating new resource in the model.
Try this.

```
     $post =  post::find($id);
        $post->type       = $request->get('type');
        $post->slug       = str_slug($request->get('title'));
        $post->title      = $request->get('title');
        $post->body       = $request->get('body');
        $post->excerpt    = $request->get('excerpt');
        $post->tag        = $request->get('tag');
        $post->metas       = $request->get('metas');
        $post->ispublished = $request->get('ispublished');
        $post->published_at = $request->get('published_at');
        $post->save();

 if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
{
 request()->validate(['image' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048']);
        $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        $update = Post::where('id', $id)->update([
                 'image' => $imageName
             ]);
        }
```

Comment: it works! thank youu. but is that an optimized way or there is another way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: This can be considered as failproof way works perfect with Mass Assignment of attributes, though it runs queries twice, but it will work for all cases, even when there's a new record and you've to update image to the record.

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting with the error because it cannot find the $imageName variable when the user does not select the image. You can assign variable even when the user does not select the image.

```
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
            {
                    request()->validate(['image' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048']);
                    $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
            }else
   {
    $imageName = null;
    }
```

Comment: if i add the else condition, the image become not found when displayed

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$imageName` before the `if` condition. For example:

```
$imageName = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an if to check if the file exist or not then update if the file exist.

```
$post             =  post::find($id);
    $post->type       = $request->get('type');
    $post->slug       = str_slug($request->get('title'));
    $post->title      = $request->get('title');
    $post->body       = $request->get('body');
    $post->excerpt    = $request->get('excerpt');
    $post->tag        = $request->get('tag');
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
    {
        $post->image = $imageName;
    }
    $post->metas       = $request->get('metas');
    $post->ispublished = $request->get('ispublished');
    $post->published_at = $request->get('published_at');
    $post->save();
```

Comment: yes but if u skipped that one ur $imageName is empty. so this will skip the save on image if there is no file present..

Answer (score 0):

Replace Only :

```php
if(isset($imageName) && $imageName !== "") {
    $post->image      = $imageName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anser by @Aditya Thakur looks good but

if the **user is updating the image**

the update query will run **two times** its not nessary

**So try the Code Below**

```
        $post =  post::find($id);
        $imageName =  $post->image;

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
        {
            request()->validate(['image' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048']);
            $uplodedObject = $request->file('image');
            $imageName = md5(time()).'.' .$uplodedObject->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $uplodedObject->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        }

        $post->type       = $request->get('type');
        $post->slug       = str_slug($request->get('title'));
        $post->title      = $request->get('title');
        $post->body       = $request->get('body');
        $post->excerpt    = $request->get('excerpt');
        $post->tag        = $request->get('tag');
        $post->image        = $imageName;
        $post->metas       = $request->get('metas');
        $post->ispublished = $request->get('ispublished');
        $post->published_at = $request->get('published_at');
        $post->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `$imageName` variable.

```
$imageName = "";

if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
    {
            request()->validate(['image' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048']);
            $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
    }
```